# Canvas painting starts from right-center instead top-center

Tags: canvas, qml

I am writing a program in qml [(my program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfSce.png)) wherein the arc/circle should get paint with yellow color on "+" button press(). Actually my code works but problem over here is it starts painting canvas from right-center. I want top-center as a starting point for canvas painting.

Can you guys please suggest me something? Seems, it is all about some mathematical calculation of start point but it is not clicking to me.

[click here to see the current code output and my expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csoqm.png)

```
# import QtQuick 2.0 
# import QtQuick.Window 2.0
Rectangle
{
    id:main
    width: 400
    height: 400
    property real counter: 0.0

    property int count: 1

    property real angle : 0;
    property int value: 0
    property int maxHours: 0

    onValueChanged:
    {
        console.log("======> canvas.maxHours = ",maxHours);
        if(maxHours < 4)
        {
            if(360 === (angle += 6))
            {
                angle = 0;//-1.5;
                if(360 === (hoursAngle += 90))
                {
                   // 0.00001 is needed to correct working ctx.arc(...) formulas on corner cases
                    angle = hoursAngle -= 0.0001
                }
                maxHours++;
            }
            canvas.requestPaint();
        }

    }

    Canvas
    {
        id: canvas

        anchors.centerIn: main

        width: 170
        height: 170
        smooth: true
        visible: true
        renderStrategy: Canvas.Threaded;
        renderTarget: Canvas.Image;
        antialiasing: true;

        onPaint:
        {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.reset()

            var centreX = width / 2;
            var centreY = height / 2;


            //M Indicator
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            ctx.moveTo(centreX, centreY);
            ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width/2 - 5, 0, 360, false); // Outer circle
            ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width/2 - 10, 0, 360, true); // Inner circle
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();


            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "yellow"
            ctx.moveTo(centreX, centreY);
            console.log("===> Ravi  centreX =",centreX)
            console.log("===> Ravi  centreY =",centreY)
            console.log("===> Ravi  angle =",angle)
            console.log("===> Ravi  angle * Math.PI / 180 =",angle * Math.PI / 180)


            ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width/2 - 5, 0,  angle * Math.PI / 180, false); // Outer circle
            ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width/2 - 10, angle * Math.PI / 180, 0, true); // Inner circle

            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id:addElement
        width:35
        height:35
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        Text
        {
            text: "+"
            font.pixelSize: 50
            anchors.centerIn: addElement
        }
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: addElement
            onClicked:
            {
                value++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `arc` method defined as below ([see the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-context2d.html#arc-method)):

```
object arc(real x, real y, real radius, real startAngle, real endAngle, bool anticlockwise)
```

Your `startAngle` is 0 so the circle is being drawn starting on what you call "right center": angles are defined according to the trigonometric circle. If you want your circle being drawn from "top center", just set your `startAngle` to `Math.PI/2`

Which gives you:

```
property real angle : -90;
...
ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width/2 - 5, -Math.PI/2,  angle * Math.PI / 180, false); // Outer circle
ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width/2 - 10, angle * Math.PI / 180, -Math.PI/2, true); // Inner circle
```

Comment: For example if you want to paint from "top center" to "right center" you do `ctx.arc(centreX, centreY, width/2 - 5, Math.PI/2, 0, false);`. The documentation sais that _Both startAngle and endAngle are measured from the x-axis in radians_

Comment: I don't want to paint circle. I want to paint the arc ( the circle boundary which is 5px in width) in every second. Purpose here is to write a clock progress bar widget. Currently, I am painting the arc using "+"  button instead timer. 

I  request you to run my source code and press "+" button for a while, it will make you my expectation more clear. 

I request, if possible, can you please put your suggestion in my shared code ?

Comment: I have run your code and the problem you encounter is the one I mentioned: you need to start not from 0 but from `Math.PI/2`. I edited my answer so that you have exactly the code you need... Moreover, you should not paint a circle then remove the inside, but use `ctx.lineWidth` instead and draw only one arc.